# Enabling JMX For Hadoop HDFS & Also MapReduce

Tags: hadoop

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to enable JMX to submit metrics for HDFS and MapReduce jobs in Hadoop (CDH4).

I've seen several links and read through 'The Definitive Guide' and 'Hadoop Operations' on the 'monitoring' chapters and it goes through a great background on Metrics1, Metrics2, JMX JSON files, and that the latter is the preferred method, but I can't find out how to enable it for HDFS and MapReduce independently.

[This blog](http://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/enabling-jmx-monitoring-for-hadoop-and-hive/) has a good intro but it doesn't monitor Task and Data Nodes.  I'm not sure how to enable it for everything.  Does anyone have any steps?  Thanks!